# How to install ruby on rails on ubuntu with rvm or rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

I am trying to setup RoR on my system (ubuntu 16.04).

I followed the rubyonrails.org, which says to install ruby and sqlite3 before installing rails. I installed ruby from rubyinstaller and sqlite3 from stackoverflow. After that, I ran:

```
gem install rails
```

but it didn't work. I found rvm. I did that, but that also didn't work. Then I found rbenv from digital ocean, and I ended up having rails and ruby installed through rbenv.

I want to know what the proper way is to install ror on a system.

Comment: What is the difference between "ruby on rails", "RoR", "rails", "and "ror"?

Comment: @sawa Oh god ! I didn't  notice that all these mistake , please forgive me , my English is too bad, by the way  "RoR", "rails", "and "ror" all these are same.

Comment: I think you should follow steps given in this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You can also use gist created by me https://gist.github.com/vishaltps/b0b5a456c337e40d3ec47df9f6073ff8

Comment: @Vishal thanks for the responce, but what is the difference  between  the installation with rvm and rbenv.?

Comment: @shashiverma You can use any rvm or rbenv for managing the version of ruby. its depend on you what you have to use

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow a completed guide in order to setup a ruby on rails environment.

Here is a good guide for ubuntu 16.04.

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04